# How to update multiple rows with same id in sql

Tags: sql-server-2012

Here is my code:
I am getting error while updating rows

```
Declare @XMLDocument XML
set @XMLDocument = 
'<EmployeeZoneMapping>
  <EmployeeZoneData>
   <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
   <ServiceCircleZoneID>3</ServiceCircleZoneID>
   <EmployeeZoneMappingStatus>1</EmployeeZoneMappingStatus>
  </EmployeeZoneData>
 <EmployeeZoneData>
<EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
<ServiceCircleZoneID>6</ServiceCircleZoneID>
<EmployeeZoneMappingStatus>0</EmployeeZoneMappingStatus>
  </EmployeeZoneData>
</EmployeeZoneMapping>'

   ;WITH XmlData AS 
(
SELECT
    A.Details_EmployeeZoneMapping.value('(EmployeeID) [1]','int') AS EmployeeID,
  A.Details_EmployeeZoneMapping.value('(ServiceCircleZoneID) [1]','tinyint') AS ServiceCircleZoneID,
  A.Details_EmployeeZoneMapping.value('(EmployeeZoneMappingStatus) [1]','bit') AS EmployeeZoneMappingStatus
from  @XMLDocument.nodes ('EmployeeZoneMapping/EmployeeZoneData') AS  A (Details_EmployeeZoneMapping))
MERGE INTO dbo.Details_EmployeeZoneMapping t 
USING XmlData x ON t.EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID 
WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN 
     UPDATE SET 
    t.ServiceCircleZoneID = x.ServiceCircleZoneID,
   t.EmployeeZoneMappingStatus = x.EmployeeZoneMappingStatus


WHEN NOT MATCHED 
   THEN 
  INSERT(EmployeeID,ServiceCircleZoneID,EmployeeZoneMappingStatus)
  VALUES(x.EmployeeID, x.ServiceCircleZoneID, x.EmployeeZoneMappingStatus)
;
```

Error:

The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: You must ensure a unique record being found. You can improve the `USING` with another condition or add a `GROUP BY` clause. Execute the `SELECT` and see the duplicate records, it will give you a clue on how can you improve your `SELECT`

Comment: I try it still error Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_EmployeeZone'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Details_EmployeeZoneMapping'. The duplicate key value is (5, 6).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I change above code as ;WITH XmlData AS 
(
    SELECT  distinct ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID order by EmployeeID ) AS RowNum,
 EmployeeID,ServiceCircleZoneID,EmployeeZoneMappingStatus from #temp 
         
)
MERGE dbo.Details_EmployeeZoneMapping t 
USING XmlData x ON t.EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID 
WHEN MATCHED and RowNum=1